# React : Sending array of objects from MongoDB(using node.js +express ) to client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I am trying to send an array of objects that I get from MongoDB to client(React.js) using Node.js. However, I keep running into `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, desc, price, purchased})` error, while I am sure I have passed the data in correct format.

What the array looks like:

```
[{
          desc:"Manage",
          price: 5000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"Deliver",
          price: 2000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"Market",
          price: 4000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"Agentone",
          price: 8000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"CPM",
          price: 14000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"Data",
          price: 17000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"E-Sign",
          price: 9000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"IGO",
          price: 3000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"DocFast",
          price: 7000,
          purchased: false,
        }
      ],
```

My server side:

```
app.get('/item_info', (req, res) => {
  var data;
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("ItemList");
    dbo.collection("ItemInfo").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.send({express: result})
      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

My client:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state={
     itemList:[]
  }
}




componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi()
          .then(res => this.setState({itemList: res.express}))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));

      console.log(this.state.data)
  }

  callApi = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/item_info');
      const body = await response.json();
      if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

      return body;
  };

  render()  {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Reactr</h1>
          </header>
        </div>
        <div>{this.state.itemList[0]}</div>
     </div>
    )}
```

In order to confirm that the client is getting the right format, I print the `res.express` to console and it shows the following:

```
(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf92", desc: "Manage", price: 5000, purchased: false}
1: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf93", desc: "Deliver", price: 2000, purchased: false}
2: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf94", desc: "Market", price: 4000, purchased: false}
3: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf95", desc: "Agentone", price: 8000, purchased: false}
4: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf96", desc: "CPM", price: 14000, purchased: false}
5: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf97", desc: "Data", price: 17000, purchased: false}
6: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf98", desc: "E-Sign", price: 9000, purchased: false}
7: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf99", desc: "IGO", price: 3000, purchased: false}
8: {_id: "5bb223f5b717bc0aa0f5cf9a", desc: "DocFast", price: 7000, purchased: false}
length: 9
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So the client is getting the correct format of array. I can't figure out why react is yelling at me

Comment: Can you show how react is "yelling" at you?

Comment: @MattKuhns I am getting an error where it says :`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, desc, price, purchased}`

Comment: @MattKuhns also, when I try to access it by doing `{this.state.itemList[0].desc}`, it says  `Cannot read property 0 of null`, so the the client does not receive the data properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render an object directly. As you can see by looking the error you get, it is not possible to do that. So, you need to render this object's properties.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Reactr</h1>
        </header>
      </div>
      <p>{this.state.itemList[0].desc}</p>
      <p>{this.state.itemList[0].price}</p>
      // and so on
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course, you don't want to render all the objects manually. So, first use `.map` method on your array then render the properties.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    itemList: [
      {
        _id: "1",
        desc: "Manage",
        price: 5000,
        purchased: false
      },
      {
        _id: "2",
        desc: "Deliver",
        price: 2000,
        purchased: false
      },
      {
        _id: "3",
        desc: "Market",
        price: 4000,
        purchased: false
      }
    ]
  };

  renderItems() {
    return this.state.itemList.map(item => (
      <div key={item._id}>
        <p>Desc: {item.desc}</p>
        <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
        {!item.purchased ? <p>Not purchased</p> : <p>Purchased</p>}
      </div>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderItems()}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `this.state.itemList[0]` returns error  `Cannot read property '0' of null`, so the real problem is the setstate where itemList does not properly gets the data

Comment: And my problem is that if I do console.log(res.express), I actually see the data, however, the setstate is just not getting it

Comment: @SpencerOvetsky, this is because your data is coming from an async operation. In the first render there is no itemList[0], so you can't get a property from `undefined`. Have you tried my code? Like mapping, then render the items? You can see one single property like this: `{ this.state.itemList[0] && this.state.itemList[0].desc }` But again, most of the time you want to map your data then render it somehow. You can also do conditional rendering again.

Comment: I did. It worked. Is there a work around besides using map? Since I need to use these data in child component and modify individual child component separately(different styling). Does using `axios` work?

Comment: At some point, you have to use `.map`. Having a child component does not affect this, instead of rendering directly just pass the `item` to the child component and do there whatever you want. `axios` or any other fetch method is not related to your issue. Your data is coming after the first render so you should do conditional rendering if you have an issue about this.

Comment: because I need to wrap up every three of my child components in a row and every child component itself in a column. and I cant seem to figure it out only using map. because within the map function, you have to return a complete div, however, if I want to wrap them in a row. The first component will have  the opening tag of <div className="row"> while the third child component will have </div> , since they only return part of the div tag, it is regard as invalid syntax.

Comment: I can't imagine the whole situation right now. You can use `React.Fragment` instead of `div` anywhere where your JSX need a wrapper. If this question's problem solved for you then please accept my answer, ask a new question and give all the details there.

Comment: You are welcome. Just try to write the code and if you hit a problem do not hesitate to ask the question.